# Java iCalendar invite as free in outlook

Tags: java, icalendar, vcalendar

I am working on a code to generate Calendar invite which can be accepted/declined in outlook. I have used java iCalendar to generate Calendar invite.

My requirement is, that when the calendar invite is accepted in outlook, it should by default show as "free" time. With my current implementation, it shows are "busy".

Appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.2.7) you should set the `TRANSP` property to `TRANSPARENT`.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this.